# Do these Precision-Recall (PR) curves indicate good classification performances?

Tags: machine-learning, roc, precision-recall, auc

I have trained a classifier for 3 different classes, the test datasets of which are imbalanced, and then plotted the PR curves (**below**) to evaluate their accuracies. The plots contain the number of positives/negatives as well as the PR-AUC. The horizontal red line represents a baseline of the random classifier.

Similarly to the ROC that is evaluated with respect to the diagonal line, which would be produced by a completely random guess, I assume that I can also evaluate the PR curve with respect to the horizontal red line.

If this assumption is correct, **can I say that the PR curves below indicate a good classification performance since they are all above the random guess line?**
[image: PR-Curve of the first class]
[image: PR-Curve of the first class]
[image: PR-Curve of the first class]

**EDIT:** figures have been updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Good" is always subjective and problem-dependent: if the classification problem is easy, one would expect to beat the random classifier by a large margin, but for a difficult classification problem performing even just a bit better than random may be enough to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

as @Franck Dernoncourt noted everything is relative. Your results just indicate that your models are better then "dumb" model.